# Is it possible to do a gradual migration to AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2

The [AFNetworking 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide) describes how to migrate from AFNetworking 1 to 2.0. However it does not mention whether it's possible to have both versions of the library live simultaneously in an application to allow for a gradual migration.

Would it be possible for an application already using [AFNetworking 1.x](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x/AFNetworking) to include the AFNetworking 2.0 pod, write new code using 2.0 and slowly port the existing code? If so, would there be any caveats or gotchas?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large your codebase is, this is not an easy transition. The changes they made for 2.0 are *great*, but if you are in the unfortunate situation of having to work with a single class derived from `AFHTTPClient` that deals with different auth scenarios, you may be in for a bit of pain.